# How to give loop variable i in the cut command?

Tags: scripts

```
while [ "$i" -lt "$b" ]
        do
          export file=$(echo $a | cut -f$i -d' ')
          echo $file
          export i=`echo $i + 1`
        done
```

My variable `"a"` has `ab cd ef` and so on. `i` need to take the words from first word to last word one at each time when loops.

This should be done based on the `i` value,

> EX: when `i=1` `i` should get first word, when `i=2` `i` should get
>   second word and so on.

Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: can we use the loop variable i in cut command like mentioned above? Pls help me

Comment: This has no relation to Ubuntu.  It is a coding question :)

Comment: Are you trying to increment the value of `i`? if so try either `i=$((i+1))` or just `((i++))` instead of `echo $i + 1`. Is this homework?

Comment: Development/coding questions are not off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to export every variable, only do it if you are spawning an external process that needs to find your variables in its environment.

bash uses square brackets for evaluating test expressions, and round parentheses for evaluating arithmetic expressions:

```
while (( i < b ))
do
    file=$(cut -f$i -d' ' <<< "$a")
    echo $file
    (( i += 1 ))
done
```

Additionally, you don't need to keep calling `cut`, you can store the words of "$a" in an array:

```
words=( $a )    # the variable is specifically *not* quoted here
for file in "${words[@]}"; do
    do_something_with $file
done
```